# Is there any browsers which connects without SSL when connect with SSL fails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ssl

I use jquery and jQuery.ajax.
And I want to connect SSL page with ajax from noSSL page.

Is there any browsers which connects server without SSL when connects server with SSL fails using ajax?

I mean if this code fails,

```
$.post('https://xxxxxx')
```

browser connect "http://xxxxxx" automatically.
Is there any browser which behave this?

I want to know security risk of jQuery.ajax .

Of course I think the behave is nonsense. But I want to get the evidence to know all browser don't behave this. So, What shold I read? I read the WC3 XMLHttpResponse. But All browser apply this specification?

Comment: I mistake code.
    $.post('https://xxxxxx')

Comment: I don't know of any browsers that automatically fall back to non-encrypted HTTP on failure. A feature like that would be considered a security/privacy risk. What you *can* do in jQuery (or in pure JavaScript for that matter) is run another `$.ajax` call on a failure response.

Answer (score 1):

If you specified https in your ajax call url, there is no reason the browser will try http(as it's not asked to). It would be, as you say, a security risk.

Imagin if you are on your bank website and for some reson their https fail. It would be a nonsense to **try** it with http